# How can I solve this : The column 'created_at' conflicts with another column in the mapper

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working on a little project with Symfony2.

I'm trying to get all entries from one day (today by default) from a table.

I first tried with `DAY()` in my doctrine query builder but that doesn't work, so I use now a native sql query in my entity repository:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Teacup\CompareBundle\Entity\Log', 'l');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Teacup\CompareBundle\Entity\Frame', 
                                       'f', 
                                       'l', 
                                       'frame', 
                                       array('id' => 'frame_id'));

$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT l.id, l.severity, 
                                        l.details, l.created_at, f.url 
                                 FROM log l 
                                 INNER JOIN frame f ON l.frame_id = f.id 
                                 WHERE DAY(l.created_at) = :day', $rsm);
```

But i get this error:

```
The column 'created_at' conflicts with another column in the mapper.
```

and I don't find how to solved it. I'm pretty sure it's nothing but, I just keep trying without any success. Can someone help me?

Comment: The entity has $createdAt and $created_at properties?

Comment: The entities have $created_at property, i changed the code below but I get the same error.

Comment: what database are you using - MySQL?  Can you post your entities?  Does the query work if you only query the log table and do not try using the join with the frame table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the DBAL layer?

```
$day = date('d');

$dbal = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('default');
$stmt = 'SELECT l.id, l.severity, l.details, l.created_at, f.url FROM log l 
         INNER JOIN frame f ON l.frame_id = f.id 
         WHERE DAY(l.created_at) = :day';

$data = $dbal->fetchAssoc( $stmt , array( 'day' => $day ) );
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify rename mode for Doctrine to automatically resolve conflicts:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em, ResultSetMappingBuilder::COLUMN_RENAMING_INCREMENT);
```

Next configure RSM as usual, then generate a select clause for your query:

```
$selectClause = $rsm->generateSelectClause()

$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT ' . $selectClause. '
                             FROM log l 
                             INNER JOIN frame f ON l.frame_id = f.id 
                             WHERE DAY(l.created_at) = :day', $rsm);
```